Renaming each band of a multiband raster when exporting as separate individual rasters using r terra package
I'm writing some code that takes a multiband raster, masks and resamples it by a reference raster, then exports and saves individual rasters for each band all within the terra package; however the names of the output rasters are giving me issues.
My code is currently:
#load library
library(terra)

#Define multiband raster path
multiband_raster_path <- "mypath.tif"

#load path raster to mask by
mask_raster_path <- "mypath.tif"

#Define Output Folder
output_directory <- "mypath_output"

#load mask raster
mask_raster <- terra::rast(mask_raster_path)

#load multiband raster
multiband_raster <- terra::rast(multiband_raster_path)

#crop multiband raster to make analysis quicker
multiband_raster <- terra::crop(multiband_raster, mask_raster)

#reproject, mask and resample multi band raster
multiband_raster <- terra::project(multiband_raster, mask_raster)
masked_raster <- terra::mask(multiband_raster, mask_raster)
resampled_raster <- terra::resample(masked_raster, mask_raster)

#define number of bands
num_bands <- terra::nlyr(resampled_raster)

# Loop through each band and save it as a separate raster
for (i in 1:num_bands) {
# Extract the i-th band
single_band <- resampled_raster[[i]]
# Define the output file path
output_file_path <- file.path(output_directory, paste0("GFDL_SSP3_2040_BIOCLIM_", i, ".tif"))
# Save the single band raster
writeRaster(single_band, output_file_path, overwrite=TRUE)


This is all working fine but I want to change the names of the individual rasters to match the file names I am designating them (E.g., GFDL_SSP3_2040_BIOCLIM_1; GFDL_SSP3_2040_BIOCLIM_2 etc). Currently they have the name of the specific band of the multiband raster input (e.g. wc2.1_30s_bioc_GFDL-ESM4_ssp370_2021-2040_1).
I think its related to the terra::names() function, but I'm not sure how to insert it into the loop to automate the renaming.
Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Welcome to Stackoverflow. What does dim(multiband_raster) report?

Thanks. dim(multiband_raster) reports:
[1] 21600 43200    19
that is, prior to any cropping, masking or resampling of the multiband raster.

Using terra::set.names
for (i in 1:nlyr(nineteen_band_rast)) {
  set.names(nineteen_band_rast, value = letters[i], index = i)
  }
names(nineteen_band_rast)
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s"

So, you create a character vector of your desired files_names <- c('file1', ..., and slip the set.names into your loop prior to write.
Well, actually, given the structure above, rename prior to the loop,
set.names(x, value = files_names, index=1:nlyr(x), validate=FALSE)

And in your loop the <- file.path(output_directory becomes
file.path(output_directory(paste0(names(nineteen_band_rast[i]), i, '.tif')))
And you might comment as to why you want these as single band files rather than layers.

Thanks Chris, this worked. This code is part of my pre-processing to do some SDM analysis under future climate conditions. The download output from WorldClim gives a Mulitband Rasters and I want to work with individual layers as individual rasters. Thanks again

It is worth noting that when you have many, many bands, organizing them as layers (by time slice?) likely simplifies things without adding memory overhead due to terra pointer and load only as needed. If the above addressed the issue, mark as accepted as this helps others trying to search to resolve similar issues, and questions with answers get visited first.
